# swift function calls: self-keyword vs without

Tags: function, swift, self

I was wondering if there is any difference between those two a function-calls in a class:

```
self.myFuction()
```

VS

```
myFunction()
```

it is working in both ways. Is there the case where it's necessary to use the self-keyword?

Comment: It's really just personal preference; for me I prefer to always use `self` because it's just more explicit about what's happening. Take for example classes with an `enumerate()` method, and the global function `enumerate()`, while it doesn't matter in this case which one is called, imagine you have your own method and global named "foo", `self` just helps to clarify which one you are calling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases: there is absolutely no difference. But it's more "swiftish" if you omit "self".
But there is a case, when you have to use self: in closure expressions.

**But** since Swift 1.2, with the @noescape parameter, you can omit "self" in closures as well.