# Should I use self for property in Swift

Tags: swift

In swift, there's no requirement for calling `self` for properties.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
     self.A = 1
     A = 1
}
```

It's cleaner *without* `self` but clearer *with* `self` for it could tell whether it's a property.

The same question for functions is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675146/swift-function-calls-self-keyword-vs-without)

Answer (score 1):

The use of `self` and `this` to certain extent could be seen as a matter of style/choice. Sometimes it really matters, like when there are conflicting values - method parameter has the same name as class property. It doesn't matter if you don't use it where it is not necessary, but keep in mind readability of the code and also consistency - if you choose to use it everywhere, **do**.